# how do a click on a link in webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to click on a link in a web page with webdriverIO.
I can navigate to google.com page and then I enter a search term.

But when I try to click on a link containing the text I want, it doesn't click the link.

What am I doing wrong:

Here is my code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        //browserName: 'phantomjs'
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};
webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .setValue('*[name="q"]','webdriverio')
    .click('*[name="btnG"]')
    .pause(1000)
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + title)
    })
    .getText('=webdriver.io').then(function(text) {
        console.log('Title was: ' + text); // outputs: "WebdriverIO"
    })
    .end();
```

I am running webdriverIO with node.js v6.9.2 and selenium stand alone server 3.0.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!!!

use:

```
.click('[href="http://webdriver.io/"]')
```

this format worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they changed the name of the "google search" button to be 'btnK'. Try replacing 'btnG' with 'btnK' in your click command and see if it works.

```
<input value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

Comment: no that is not the issue. I can get to google.com and search for webdriverio just fine. Its cicking on a link in the page itself that is my issue.